# PHP: Making an array of strings inside foreach then add all the result of arrays of strings

Tags: php, arrays, string

**Problem:** Hi, Im having a hard time making a foreach in PHP, that has arrays of strings, then I will add all those strings in a one single string or store in a single variable.

**Purpose:** My purpose for this is because I want to make an echo substr() of the total of all strings which is for my other reasons.

**What I've done so far:**

```
<?php 

    $values = array();

    foreach ($acknowledgementspecifics as $specifics);
    {
    ?>  

    <?php $values = array[]("".$specifics->feetype_name." (".$specifics->month_date.") ".$specifics->payment_amount.", "); ?>

    <?php
     }

// (Combine all Arrays)

// $totalvalue = (total of all combined strings);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

- The `;` at the end of the `foreach` line will create a loop without any body. The part that follows it is *not* part of the `foreach` body. So remove the `;`.
- The syntax to append to an array is not `$values = array[]( ... )`, but `$values[] = ...`

After those fixes, you will have the array of strings, which you then need to concatenate to one string, which you can do with `implode`. You need to provide a delimiter to separate the strings (e.g. `\n` or `<br>`):

```
$values = array();
foreach ($acknowledgementspecifics as $specifics) {
    $values[] = $specifics->feetype_name . " (".
                $specifics->month_date . ") ".
                $specifics->payment_amount . ", "; 
}
// (Combine all Arrays)
$totalvalue = implode("\n", $values);
```

Comment: Thanks this is the best answer, easy to understand and thanks for those corrections.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store all values in a string in a forecah loop, ignore use of array, use **(.=)** operator. now you can use use **substr()** function.
see the code -
use substr() function

```
<?php 
    $values = "";
    foreach ($acknowledgementspecifics as $specifics){
        $values. = "".$specifics->feetype_name." (".$specifics->month_date.") ".$specifics->payment_amount.", ";
    }

    $totalvalue=$values; // (All Values)
//now you can use substr()
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the string to the array...

```
$values[] = $specifics->feetype_name
       ." (".$specifics->month_date.") "
       .$specifics->payment_amount;
```

And to add them together use either `implode(',', $values)` or just `implode($values)`